# Can I access profile information if I use OpenID login?

Tags: facebook, openid

I am going to add a login area to my website, and I am considering using OpenID to handle the login process.

However, I want to require the user to input 'company name', 'industry' and 'country' in order to sign up (for our database marketing).

Questions:

1. Is it possible to use OpenID and at the same time require input of these special data fields?
2. If the user logs in using OpenID from, for example, Facebook or Google, am I able to access the user's profile information on those sites during or after the authentication process? (Again, this is for database marketing.)

I appreciate that it is bad taste to require input of this personal info to sign up, however this is our company policy and we offer valuable contents in return for the profile data.

Answer (score 1):

With Google, you'll be able to get the country with the [attribute exchange](http://code.google.com/intl/zh-TW/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html#AuthProcess), it's not difficult to get it.

With Facebook, if the user has added that information, you'll be able to get them too.

Once you complete your requests, verify that you got everything you wanted. If not, prompt the user with a form for the missing information.